# fgets() doesn't wait for input running with Eclipse-neon

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-neon

my main function calls another function that it's 3 first lines are:

```
char input[1024];
printf("Please enter the difficulty level between [1-7]:\n");
fgets(input, 1024, stdin);
```

and for some reason the fgets doesn't wait for my input.

Just to clarify - the first thing (except from initializing ints and stuff like that) is to call that function.

and i'm not using scanf in the entire code.

What might be the problem?? THANK YOU!

edit:

this is my main function:

```
int main(){
    int check = 0;
    char input[1024];
    int level = getLevel(); //get the difficulty level from the user
    while ( level>7 || level<1 ) level = getLevel();
    return level
 }
```

and this is the getLevel Function:

```
int getLevel(){
    int level = 1;
    char input[1024];
    bool isNum = true;
    printf("Please enter the difficulty level between [1-7]:\n");
    fgets(input, 1024, stdin); //gets the input from the user
    isNum = InputIsInt(input);
    if(!isNum){ //input is not a number
        return 0;
    }
    level = atoi(input);
    return level;
}
```

and this is the InputIsInt function: (Working fine)

```
bool InputIsInt(const char* str){
    if(!str ||!*str){
    return false;
    }
    if(*str=='-'){//if the number is negative
        ++str;
    }
    while(((*str)!='\0')&&((*str)!='\n')){
        if (!isdigit(*str)){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            ++str;
        }
    }
    return true;
 }
```

and well, The program doesn't stop (because the getLevel function keep returning 0).

**ANOTHER EDIT:**

It seems that running the program in the terminal does work (the fgets is "waiting" for my input) and now that I changed the InputIsInt function as suggested the program runs as I wanted it to.

*BUT* only in the terminal. When I try to run it in the IDE (I'm using Eclipse Neon), the fgets still isn't waiting for my input...
Any thought?

**LAST AND FINAL EDIT:**

I tried to use Virtual Studio instead of Eclipse Neon and it seems to have solve all of my problems (regarding this code, My life is still a mess :) ).

Comment: How do you know? Please post an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Please post more than those 3 lines and the output you get.

Comment: I can safely bet 5 euros on the fact that somebody calls `scanf` before, which leaves the newline into the read buffer, which makes `fgets` return immediately.

Comment: I think, now this question doesn't seem to be off topic after MCVE

Comment: There's no [mcve] there.

Comment: The problem comes from the IDE eclipse-neon, let's give them a chance to provide a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

You did not post a full program that exhibits the problem.

A very likely cause for `fgets()` to not wait for input is if you have previously parsed some other input with `scanf("%d", ...)` or `scanf("%s, ...)`.  The trailing newline is still pending in the `stdin` buffer and is read by `fgets()`, hence returning immediately.

If you are not using `scanf()`, it is also possible that you are running your program in an environment where `stdin` is bound to an empty file or a closed terminal.  Some IDEs have this problem, run the program in a terminal window.

In any case, you should check the return value of `fgets()`.  Here is an improved version of your code:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int getLevel(void) {
    char input[1024];

    printf("Please enter the difficulty level between [1-7]:\n");
    if (fgets(input, 1024, stdin) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fgets failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 0;
    }
    if (!InputIsInt(input)) { //input is not a number
        return 0;
    }
    return atoi(input);
}

bool InputIsInt(const char *str) {
    if (!str || !*str) return false;
    if (*str == '-') { //if the number is negative
        ++str;
    }
    size_t digits = strspn(str, "0123456789");
    return (digits > 0 && (str[digits] == '\0' || str[digits] == '\n');
}
```

Comment: okay, so after a few twiks it works only in a terminal window, while in the IDE the program still doesn't stop to get my input.
Is there anything I can do about it? or do I have to use another IDE?
(I'm using Eclipse Neon)

Comment: @Omered: I'm not familiar with Eclipse Neon, Edit the question to add this comment and add the eclise tag.

Comment: How does this solve the problem?

Comment: @VidorVistrom: the problem is not in the code, but producing informative error messages usually help identify the cause of the problem: `fgets()` fails. The behavior would have been different if a `scanf()` had left a pending newline in `stdin`.

Comment: Okay so you checked for fgets returning null but the newline still gets appended to the end of the string. OP seemed to have  edited the question with the answer I provided and took it as a suggestion. Now the the question is it is not working with eclipse. Since a solution is not there yet, I suggest to uncheck this post.  Moreover, you just told the problem which wasn't even there in the OPs code. There is no scanf before fgets here.

Comment: @VidorVistrom: When I initially answered his question, the OP had not given all relevant information.  This answer was edited iteratively and did provide all the necessary hints as to what the problem was and how to fix it.  Your answer addressed some of the issues, but be aware that `if(input[strlen(input)-1]=='\n')` has undefined behavior in 2 cases: if `fgets()` failed, which was not tested, and if a null byte was read from `stdin`, which is rare but not impossible.  I don't know what Eclipse attaches to stdin, but running the program there was the most important factor in the OP's problem.

Comment: I am not accusing of wrong answer dude. Instead I am just asking to OP, to not select an answer until his problem is completely solved. Imagine a newbie using eclipse, failed with fgets land up here. He sees an accepted answer, which does not help. Sure your idea is perfect for first iteration, but the final cake which he provides surely lacks some ingredients which he fail to search for. And if someone else tries the same recipe he would fail too.

Answer (score 0):

This code works on its own, but it is possible you are running from a context where stdin does not correspond with "stdin" of the main program. For example, if you fork:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {

    int pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){
        char input[1024];
        printf("Please enter the difficulty level between [1-7]:\n");
        fgets(input, 1024, stdin);
    } else if (pid < 0) { /* checking for error */
        ; // error here
    } else {
       wait(NULL); // wait for child to return
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In the above case, you are running fgets from a child process which has its own stdin. One way you could address this by calling fgets before the fork here.

Comment: A possible explanation, but I believe there must be a simpler one.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this right after your fgets()

```
if(input[strlen(input)-1]=='\n'){
        input[strlen(input)-1]='\0';
    }
```

What was happening was, in your `bool InputIsInt(const char* str){}` function,

```
if (!isdigit(str[i])){
                return false;
            }
```

was returning false on the last element in the input array, which was *\n*(New line). Just replace it by *\0*(null character). *fgets()* also allocate that newline character if the input was found less than the provided range(in this case 1024). Had the user entered a number greater than 1024 digits, it would be okay. But its always a good practice to check for newline character after fgets().

---

Don't forget to include ***string.h***